# Why are all of my stylesheets being included on my page when using assets pipeline?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I have a file structure that looks like this:

```
/stylesheets
  application.css.scss
  home.css.scss
  /office_listings
    new.css.scss
    index.css.scss
    show.css.scss
  /neighborhoods
    show.css.scss
    index.css.scss
```

and so on. My application includes a require_tree statement. I thought this would compile all of my CSS into the application.css.scss file. But when I visit the page on my local host and inspect the page resources, I not only see my application.css.scss file, I also see every other CSS file I've made. The same holds true for my javascript files.

I tried running rake assets:clean and manually deleting any files cached in my public folder just in case it was an issue with rake assets:precompile which I ran a few times, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: What is the contents of your <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %> in your application.html.erb layout?

Comment: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %> is all it has

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior if you are running the Rails application in the `development` environment (the default). By default, `development` is configured with `config.assets.debug` set to `true`, which causes all asset files to be served individually to ease debugging - the browser's CSS inspector will show you the correct file a rule originates from, rather than always pointing to the single generated single.

However, if you precompile and run the app in the `production` environment, only one file is generated and served. You can test this by running the following commands:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
RAILS_ENV=production rails server
```

If you visit your site now, you should see only a single `application.css` file with all of your stylesheets combined. (Make sure your `config/environments/production.rb` file contains `config.serve_static_assets = true` - otherwise, you won't get any stylesheet at al and will just see unstyled HTML.)

For more details, I recommend the section "Turning debugging off" in the [Rails guide on the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-debugging-off).

Comment: When I do this, none of my assets are loaded and I get a vanilla HTML page. Any reason this would happen?

Comment: This usually happens if the assets have not been precompiled, as in `production` mode there is no on-demand compilation as there is in `development`. If you have done so as in the description, then I don't know what else could cause this.

Comment: @user1427661, If you are not seeing any assets after you've done `rake assets:precompile`, check to make sure in your `config/environments/production.rb` that you have `config.serve_static_assets = true` so that the assets are served from the `public/assets` directory which is where the `assets:precompile` dumps the compiled assets.

Comment: @user1427661 Good catch, I'm going to add this to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `config.assets.debug = true` in your `config/environments/{environment}.rb` where `{environment}` could be `development`, `production` etc, then all of your asset files will be expanded like you've mentioned.

Change that line to `config.assets.debug = false` and you will only see `application.css` and `application.js`.